# Redirect twice via htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to generate thumbnail images dynamically. There is simplifyed example.
User requests 
/fakeimagespath/image_name.400x400.jpg 
Where 400x400 is desired thumbnail size.
If this image exists in folder /realpath/image_name.400x400.jpg - we show it via .htaccess internal redirect.

If this image not exists I want an internal redirect to
/generator.php?name=image_name&size=400x400
This php file will generate it from source file and output with jpeg mime type.

Please help with the mod_revrite rules.

```
#index.php prints $_SERVER for debug purposes.
#cup.jpg, girl.jpg - existing files, 404.jpg - not exists

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 ^fakeimage
RewriteRule ^(fakeimage\-(cup|girl|404)\.jpg)$ /realpath/$2.jpg

RewriteCond $1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?found=$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?notfound=$1 [L]
```

**UPDATE (Example):**

```
/shop/some-user-friendly-alias.999.400x500.jpg
```

I rewrite it to REAL path /images/999/400x500.jpg
But this image not exists and I want to generate thumbnail on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a script I use. You may adapt it to your needs.

Put a .htaccess in `/` with the following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^imgresize/(.+)$ imgresize/imgresize.php
```

The following code is in `/imgresize/imgresize.php`

```
<?php
// no image requested
if(!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit;
}
// thumbnail already exists (should never be called as the .htaccess is handling this)
if(file_exists('../'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    header('Content-type: image'); 
    readfile('../'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}

// extract new width, new height and filename from request
preg_match_all('%/imgresize/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/(.+)$%isU', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
$new_width = $matches[1][0];
$new_height = $matches[2][0];
$filename = $matches[3][0];
// file doesn't exist
if(!file_exists('../'.$filename)) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit;
}

// get width, height and file format from the original image
list($ori_width, $ori_height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize('../'.$filename);

// create new image
if($type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
    $ori_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('../'.$filename);
}
elseif( $type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
    $ori_image = imagecreatefromgif('../'.$filename);
}
elseif( $type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
    $ori_image = imagecreatefrompng('../'.$filename);
}

// calculate new image ratio
$src_x = $src_y = 0;
if($ori_height/$new_height > $ori_width/$new_width) {
    $old_height = $ori_height;
    $ori_height = $ori_width/($new_width/$new_height);
    $src_y = $old_height/2 - $ori_height/2;
}
else {
    $old_width = $ori_width;
    $ori_width = $ori_height/($new_height/$new_width);
    $src_x = $old_width/2 - $ori_width/2;
}

// resize original image
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopyresampled($new_image, $ori_image, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $new_width, $new_height, $ori_width, $ori_height);

// create path
$new = $new_width.'x'.$new_height.'/'.$filename;
$parts = explode('/', $new);
$path = '';
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($parts)-1;$i++) {
    $path .= $parts[$i].'/';
    if(!file_exists($parts[$i])) {
        mkdir($path);
    }
}

// save the created image
imagejpeg($new_image, $new, 90);

// sent the created image to the user
header('Content-Type: image');
imagejpeg($new_image, null, 90);
?>
```

Now change image paths from e.g. `/images/frontpage/head.jpg` to `/imgresize/300x500/images/frontpage/head.jpg` (300=width, 500=height). If the image is already resized, the PHP script won't be called at all (the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` in the .htaccess), only the image is served to the user. If the resized image doesn't exist, it will be created, saved as `/imgresize/300x500/images/frontpage/head.jpg` (so the virtual path from the first request will become the real path for all following requests) and sent to the user.

Comment: Thank you Reeno, I'm sure this code works, but I can't use this workaround, because images should have aliases, that aren't real file names. Example: /shop/some-user-friendly-alias.999.400x500.jpg SO I rewrite it to REAL path /images/999/400x500.jpg, but this image not exists and I want to generate it.

Comment: You can adapt the regex to your needs.

Comment: Yupp! But I can't check this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f, because this file not exist, I need two levels of rewriting. ^we need to go deeper^. First rewrite - to real path, if this path not exists - to the generator.php

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

# images exists in /realpath/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/realpath/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^fakeimages/([^.]+\.[^.]+\.jpg)$ /realpath/$1 [L,NC]

# images doesn't exist in /realpath/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^fakeimages/([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.jpg$ /generator.php?name=$1&size=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Sorry for inconvenience caused.
Done by two .htaccess files.
First - inside root dir: **/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 ^fooimage
RewriteRule ^(fooimage\-(cup|girl|404)\.jpg)$ /realpath/$2.jpg [L]
```

Second inside realpath: **/realpath/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^generate\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ generate.php?notfound=$1 [L]
```

So if real image is not found script will generate it!